# Nested Form: Resource adds dynamically but doesnt get created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I am using the [nested form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) and i add products dynamically to the form. When i do click "add", another product resource appears but on creation it ERASES the former ones from being created entirely. This is how the scenario goes:

1. Fill in Location
2. Choose Date
3. Fill in Product ( one is already on form)
4. Add 5 more products (Products 2, 3, 4, 5)
5. Fill in All Products
6. "click" Create
7. Created Product 5

---

This is how my nested form looks:

```
<%= nested_form_for @location, :url => products_path(@product) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :business %>
    <%= f.text_field :business %>
    <%= f.label :address %>
    <%= f.text_field :address %>

 <%= f.fields_for :product_dates, :url => products_path(@product) do |d| %>
     <%= d.label :date %>
     <%= d.date_select :date %>

 <%= d.fields_for :products, :url => products_path(@product) do |p| %>
     <%= p.text_field :name %>
     <%= p.text_field :price %>
     <%= p.text_field :tag_list %>
     <%= p.link_to_remove "Remove Product" %>       
     <% end %>
     <%= d.link_to_add "Add", :products %>
 <% end %>
 <%= f.submit "Finish" %>
<% end %>
```

### Controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @location = Location.new
        @product = Product.new
        product_date = @location.product_dates.build
        product_date.products.build
    end

    def create
        @location = Location.create(params[:location])
        if @location.save
            flash[:notice] = "Products Created."
            redirect_to :action => 'index' 
        else
            render :action => 'new'
        end
  end
```

### Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  has_many :products,  :dependent => :destroy
end


class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :address, :business, :product_dates_attributes
    has_many :products
    has_many :product_dates 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_dates    
end

class ProductDate < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :date, :products_attributes
    belongs_to :location
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :products
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :price, :tag_list
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :location
    belongs_to :product_date
end
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Possibly a problem with your model code. Can you post your model relationships and accepts_nested_attributes for declarations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove the url_for declarations on the fields_for declarations so you get

```
<%= nested_form_for @location, :url => products_path(@product) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :business %>
    <%= f.text_field :business %>
    <%= f.label :address %>
    <%= f.text_field :address %>

    <%= f.fields_for :product_dates do |d| %>
       <%= d.label :date %>
       <%= d.date_select :date %>

       <%= d.fields_for :products do |p| %>
         <%= p.text_field :name %>
         <%= p.text_field :price %>
         <%= p.text_field :tag_list %>
         <%= p.link_to_remove "Remove Product" %>       
       <% end %>
       <%= d.link_to_add "Add", :products %>
    <% end %>
 <%= f.submit "Finish" %>
<% end %>
```

What is really confusing is your whole routing and params approach. It's just not right. You have a form_for @location with a :url products_path(@product) This will right royally cause issues with the params that are sent back and there in lies the problem.
Stick with routing to location controller not the products controller by removing the products_path(@product) form your nested_form_for declaration and you will find that you will have all the necessary records saved but you will most likely need to change the redirect_to declaration in the locations_controller create action and the same for the update_action.

But why use the products controller at all when you are dealing with a location? Again this just isn't natural or intuitive.

One last thing. Your remove links won't work as you have not added the necessary :dependent => :destroy declaration to the has_many declarations and you are also missing the :reject_if procs and the :allow_destroy => true declarations on the accepts_nested_attributes declarations.

Can I strongly suggest that you
1) Use either the locations controller or the products controller not both
I mean link to get to this form link_to the locations controller and set everything up there or use form_for @product rather than @location and handle everything in the products controller

2) watch the railscasts that this gem is based on very closely
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

3) Spend some time learning about how rails form view helpers arrange for the params hash to be organised in the controllers actions. In your case, have a close look at your log file for the parameters that come into the create action as things currently stand.
You will most likely see that the params are not nested as you would exect them to be which is why the nested attributes declaration is not behaving as expected

Comment: I wanted to use the ProductsController because i needed a place to create Products only (nested_form products/new) and a place to create Locations only (locations/new) but being new to all of this i am not sure how to go about that. Plus, i don't have any Location views right now. The location is going to be created with find_by_or_create on the nested form and users can add more details to it if they would like (categories). I have a Locations and Products Controller right now and no ProductDate controller.

Comment: So in other words, the scenario plays out like this: Users add products and have to specify a product date and a location for as many as they dynamically add. The location is created if it doesn't exist already by users typing in the address and the business name. They can choose to add details to a location by going to locations/edit because locations cannot be deleted and only updated with more information. I didn't want the form to be Location based but more Product based. My routes are all separate for this reason, i didn't want locations/1/product/new or something along those lines.

Comment: Let me digest that for a while and I'll get back to you with a solution that will work for your scenario

Comment: That would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I have had 3 attempts at answering this now but it is clear that I do not know enough about your business logic to give you the right solution and this is probably not the best place to discuss your requirements. Perhaps this is better solved in a chat room and then I can update the answer once I have a better idea of the scenario?

Comment: Yeah it would help greatly because i think i may be going about this all wrong, how should we get the chat room started?

Comment: I got one started and sent you an invite http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1787/room-for-jamesw-and-justinror